# Poor alignment of the nav bar and distortion in mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Logo, search bar, cart, login and sign up not aligned in a same line.

When i try to see the mobile view, distortion take place

search bar and other thing get messed up

and in mobile view nothing happens on clicking on menu collapsing button.

here is my code :

```
  <div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
           <div class = "container">
              <div class ="navbar-header">
                <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="hello.com">
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand"><img src="images/logo.jpg" height="60" width="200"></a>
        </div>
        <div class ="collapse navbar-collapse" id = "example">
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="cart.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md navbar-btn">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="badge"><?php echo count($_SESSION["cart_array"]); ?></span>
       </button></a>
                <li id="login"><a href="login.php" id="login1">Login</a></li>
                    <li id="login"><a href="signup.php" id="login1">Sign Up</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <form action="index.php" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type = "text" class="form-control" placeholder="search your phone" id ="search">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="bt btn-primary navbar-btn" >Submit</button>
            </form>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you give us a jsfiddle

Comment: we can help in better way if jsfiddle.

Comment: indenting your code should have made your work so much easier

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple of wrong things in your code.

### [working bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jRTsuCTAfc)

Your data-target is wrong in the `button tag`. it should be pointing to an `id` not a `link`. It should be pointing to the id of the collapsing div which in this case is example.

```
<button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example">
```

You are assigning width and height of your image instead of doing that, use the bootstrap classes to your advantage: `img-responsive`

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">
              <img src="http://thewowstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/the-best-wallpapers.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="height: 30px; margin-top: -5px;">
            </a>
          </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                   <a href="cart.php">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md navbar-btn">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          <span class="badge"><!--?php echo count($_SESSION["cart_array"]); ?--></span>
                      </button>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li id="login">
                   <a href="login.php" id="login1">Login</a>   
                </li>
                <li id="login">
                   <a href="signup.php" id="login1">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
           <form action="index.php" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
               <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search your phone" id="search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="bt btn-primary navbar-btn">Submit</button>
          </form>
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
```